# Function and Product Types Peculiarity

Tags: vdm-sl

What is the difference between the types

```
(seq of nat * seq of nat) -> nat
```

and

```
seq of nat * seq of nat -> nat
```

According to the Language Reference Manual `*` has higher precedence than `->` so the parentheses have no effect; the are semantically the same. But consider the function definitions

```
length: (seq of nat * seq of nat) -> nat
length (mk_(l,m)) == len l + len m;

length0: seq of nat * seq of nat -> nat
length0 (l,m) == len l + len m;
```

Each uses one of the types, and the patterns used in the definitions have to be different to pass type checking. It seems there is a difference between the two types. What is going on here? By parenthesising it interprets the argument as a product, but without the parentheses there are two arguments but somehow the argument type of the function is still a product. It is rather confusing. Can someone clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is confusing. In effect, brackets are being used for two purposes here, and it isn't made clear in the grammar. In isolation, brackets can be used in a type declaration to indicate groupings and overcome the default precedence. This is as you would expect. But in a function definition, top level brackets  and stars are also to identify separate parameter types.

So "nat * nat -> nat" is trying to indicate that this is a function with two parameters, rather than that this is a function that takes a single argument of a product type. So how can you indicate that you genuinely want a single product argument? Answer: with brackets :-)

So the outermost layer of bracketing and product operators in a function definition are used to group parameters types, but deeper brackets and stars have the usual meaning. The grammar is misleading when it says that the parameters/return type is a "function type" - syntactically this is true, but the way the type is then interpreted is special, in order to pull out the parameter number and types for the function.

Comment: * and it might be worth adding something about this to the Language Reference Manual.

Comment: Seems to me the reason this occurs is because VDM chooses to create a special syntax for product values, namely "mk_(x,y)". If you consider Haskell, product values are like "(x,y)" so when it comes to function application you just have "f(x,y)" whereas VDM can have "f(x,y)" or "f(mk_(x,y))". As a result, in Haskell you don't get this type confusion.

Comment: And passing a tuple as one argument in Haskell? Would that be f((x,y))? In that case the difference isn't that great.

Comment: No, Haskell does not require that function parameters be wrapped in parentheses like VDM. 'f(x,y)' is ok, but 'f((x,y))' is ok as well, and identical. '((x,y))' is just '(x,y)' wrapped in parentheses. Also means that in Haskell you can just do 'f p' is p is a pair such as '(1,2)', while VDM requires 'f(p)'.